# Use GROUP_CONCAT in MySQL with considering null

Tags: mysql, concatenation, group-concat

I have a table with 3 fields. This table keeps record of call duration for each day to the relevant country for last 30 days.

```
C_Date      Country         C_Time  
2012-10-01  India           1316
2012-10-01  USA             12  
2012-10-01  UK              132     
2012-10-01  Kuwait          134     
2012-10-02  UK              135     
2012-10-02  USA             136     
2012-10-02  Singapore       137
```

I need to generate a table and a line graph using this records and I tried to write the MySQL query. Basically I need to draw this only for selected countries.
Say I want India, USA and UK ; then I need to pull a record set like this:

```
C_Date     | Calling_Time
-----------+----------------------------------
2012-10-01 | 1316,12,132
2012-10-02 | 0,136,135
2012-10-03 | ...
...        | ...
```

This is my Query:

```
SELECT C_Date, GROUP_CONCAT(C_Time
ORDER BY Country
SEPARATOR ',') as Calling_Time
FROM Call_Table t
WHERE Country
IN ('India', 'USA', 'UK')
GROUP BY C_Date
ORDER BY  C_Date
```

The result was much closer, but it had ignored the empty results.

```
C_Date     | Calling_Time
-----------+----------------------------------
2012-10-01 | 1316,12,132
2012-10-02 | 136,135   (expected 0,136,135)
```

Can I change my query to get the Calling_Time like **0,136,135** OR **,136,135** OR **null,136,135** ?(with unique numbers of segments to represent each country )

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query -

```
SELECT
  C_Date,
  CONCAT(MAX(IF(country = 'India', C_Time, 0)), ',',
         MAX(IF(country = 'USA', C_Time, 0)), ',',
         MAX(IF(country = 'UK', C_Time, 0))) Calling_Time
  FROM call_table
  GROUP BY C_Date

+------------+--------------+
| C_Date     | Calling_Time |
+------------+--------------+
| 2012-10-01 | 1316,12,132  |
| 2012-10-02 | 0,136,135    |
+------------+--------------+
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT   aa.C_Date, 
         GROUP_CONCAT(COALESCE(bb.C_Time,0) ORDER BY bb.Country) Calling_Time
FROM
(
    SELECT a.Country, b.C_DATE
    FROM
          ( 
              SELECT DISTINCT Country
              FROM TableName t
              WHERE Country IN ('India', 'USA', 'UK')
          ) a CROSS JOIN
          (
              SELECT DISTINCT DATE(C_Date) C_Date
              FROM TableName t    
          ) b
) aa LEFT JOIN TableName bb
     ON aa.Country = bb.Country AND
        aa.C_DATE = DATE(bb.C_DATE)
GROUP BY aa.C_Date
```

- [**SEE SQLFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/858e1/33)